# How can I remove "thank you" page after login

Tags: members, login, solspace-user

I'm looking at the best way to remove the dreaded "thank you, you are now logged in" page after login.

I'm using Solspace User to manage user accounts and for registration.

I'm using the NSM Email Login to allow user's to login with their email address.

I've already tried to use Twomile Login Redirect to remove this screen but it won't work as we have MySQL in "strict" mode due a Solspace User requirement.

The only other thing I see is FreeMember but due to already using two other add ons I don't want to go and cause issues with those.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can style such a page but unsure if you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Whoops, I see you are already aware of Freemember and don't want to use another add-on. I think that, or a custom add-on as jrothafer mentioned (still another add-on!) is the way to go. Or as Mark mentioned, you can style the system message templates. *CP  > Design > Message Pages > User Messages*

---

If you're open to installing an additional add-on, [Freemember's login tag](https://github.com/devdemon/freemember/blob/master/docs/login_tag.md) bypasses the interstitial "Thank you, you are now logged in"  EE system message page.

Freemember also has lots of other useful features, including an improved forgot/reset password flow. You can use Freemember and Solspace User on the same install.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy pal, probably your best option is to craft yourself an extension that does a redirect. I would use one of the top three hooks on this page:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/member_auth/index.html

I'll give you an example, but I'm not entirely sure if it will work (you do know how to make your own extensions, correct?):

Hook to this thing:

```
member_member_login_single($hook_data)
```

And have your extension method look something like this:

```
function my_extension($hook_data)
{
    // lets get out of here!
    ee()->functions->redirect('where/we/going');
}
```

It might not be that exact hook, but one of them should be triggered before the redirect to the "Thank you" page.